# HTML, eliminate box with input 'submit'

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I eliminate the 'button' in my input field? I want to use an image, but the box still appears.
Thanks,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "">
<head>
<style>
#PlusMinus{background:url('images/sprites.gif') 0px -391px;left:0px;width:13px;}
#PlusMinus a:hover{background: url('images/sprites.gif') 0px -406px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var fontSizes = [14, 16]
    $(function(){
      $('#PlusMinus').click(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "+") {
            $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[1] + 'px');
        $(this).val("-");
        }
        else {
        $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[0]+ 'px');
        $(this).val("+");
    }
       $("body .h6").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h6 class="noSpan">
      <!--HERE'S THE INPUT-->
      <input 'submit' id='PlusMinus' />
      <span class="h6">Larger</span>
      <span class="h6" style="display: none">Smaller</span>
    </h6>
    <h5 id="OurText" class="p">TEXT</h5>
</body>
</html>
```

I've used input 'submit, image, and button', and still get this box

```
input 'submit' id='PlusMinus'
```

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the background to none, the border to none and the background color to none.

```
#PlusMinus{
background: none;
background-color: none;
border: none;
background-image: URL(../images/yourimage.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

You can then also set the height and width to this element to make it fit your background image perfectly.

Also make sure to use the type setting for the input you want

type="button"
type="submit"

et cetera

Comment: #PlusMinus is suppose to show. It the input box that's the problem

Comment: @FXquincy not sure I follow you. You wanted the input element with the id 'PlusMinus' to have a image instead of the raw input element correct?

Comment: That's right. I'm either breaking the script or getting the button and CSS image at the same time.

Comment: @ a.stgeorge I'm testing on Firefox

Comment: @FXqunicy - ok using FF shouldn't matter the above CSS is 2.1x and will work in any browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="image" src="[path]" />
```

you need the "type" attribute

Comment: Ahh a few seconds faster than me :) +1

Comment: @FXquincy, if you want a background image for whatever input you have (submit, text, button etcetera) you need to set that in the CSS as I mentioned in my answer :)